# asp.net mvc dataannotation validating url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can some one tell me how can i validate a url like http://www.abc.com

Comment: What do you mean 'validate', validate for what? As a valid URL? As a real, accessible web site? Validate the colour?

Comment: I have define the pattern http://www.abc.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If, by the title of your post, you want to use MVC DataAnnotations to validate a url string, you can write a custom validator:

```
public class UrlAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public UrlAttribute() { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //may want more here for https, etc
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(http://)?(www\.)?\w+\.(com|net|edu|org)");

        if (value == null) return false;

        if (!regex.IsMatch(value.ToString())) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Phil Haack has a good tutorial that goes beyond this and also includes adding code to validate on the client side via jQuery:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Answer (score 40):

Let the System.Uri do the heavy lifting for you, instead of a RegEx:

```
public class UrlAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public UrlAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var text = value as string;
        Uri uri;

        return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) && Uri.TryCreate(text, UriKind.Absolute, out uri ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Now (at least form ASP.NET MVC 5) you can use UrlAttribute and that includes server and client validation:

```
[Url]
public string WebSiteUrl { get; set; }
```

Comment: There is a problem with localhost, because it doesn't have 1st level domain

Comment: Note that if you want to also make sure it is not-null then you also need `Required` so it needs to be `[Required,Url]` to cover the not-null case as well.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using MVC3 RTM, you can just use [URL] validation attribute.

Refer http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/05/new-validation-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-3-future.aspx

Comment: +1 and Many thanks for the Helpful link to the nice article., :)

Answer (score 5):

What about using **URL** attribute, like:

```
public class ProveedorMetadata
{
    [Url()]
    [Display(Name = "Web Site")]
    public string SitioWeb { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I thought so, too. That only works for HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP. If you want other URLs - like mailto or file! - you're screwed, which is normal for Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Here is proper validation attribute code used in prod system:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UriValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            return true;
        }

        try
        {
            Uri result;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(value.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out result))
            {
                if (result.Scheme.StartsWith("http") || result.Scheme.StartsWith("https"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression data annotation, and use a regex like:

```
http://www\.\w+\.(com|net|edu|org)
```

Depending on what you need to validate; are you requiring http: or are you requiring www.?  So that could change the regular expression, if optional, to:

```
(http://)?(www\.)?\w+\.(com|net|edu|org)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this regular expression for Internal or external URLS on my site.

```
((?:https?\:\/\/|\/.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET Framework 4.5 all the way thru to .NET 7+, you can use the `Url` attribute on the model's property.

```
[Url]
public string MyUrl { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute?view=net-6.0

Answer (score -1):

[Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) checks that the URL format is correct and does not require escaping.

```
/// <summary>
/// Ensures the property is a valid URL.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidateUrlAttribute :  ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidateUrlAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Do not validate missing URLs - people can use [Required] for that.
        string text = (value as string) ?? "";

        if (text == "")
            return true;

        return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(text, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
}
```