# Attribute for validationUri

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class MyClass
    {
        [Required]
        public string CallBack { get; set; }
    }
```

how can I add validation to check for valid uri?
thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249105/mvc4-url-validation

Answer (score 1):

`[Url]` attribute is what you need.

[image: url attribute]

Or you can create custom validation. You can find way how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061463/asp-net-mvc-dataannotation-validating-url/33031318#comment3143503_3061463)

Comment: I am using .net framework 4.61 it seems that the Url attribute does not exists.

Comment: @AviadHasidof, then follow instructions how to create your own custom validation. It should work for your case as well

Comment: I Eventually used FluentValidation that solved my issue.